# Docker is not able to be installed on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker

I am doing the steps as shown below to install docker:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install docker`

The to start docker I am using `sudo service docker start`.But then it says `docker : unrecognized service`. I have followed every steps , is there any step missing in this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove all old packages by using this command.

```
sudo apt-get remove docker*
```

I think you have to install repo by using following command.

if you use 64bit Ubuntu version

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

and after that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install docker.io
```

And confirm version by using

```
dom@dom-pc:~/web$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.7.4
 Git commit:   XXXXXXX
 Built:        Tue Mar 14 09:47:15 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Answer (score 2):

and if you wanted to upgrade to a later version

- ls /usr/bin | grep docker 
  remove these files 
     *docker 

     docker-containerd 

     docker-containerd-ctr 

     docker-containerd-shim 

     dockerd 

     docker-init 

     docker-proxy 

     docker-runc*
- wget
  https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.06.1-ce.tgz
  (or whatever stable version you wanted)
- tar xfvz docker-17.06.1-ce.tgz
- cp docker/* /usr/bin/
- docker -v 
   and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

- $ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
- $ sudo apt-get update
- $ sudo apt-get install docker-ce

Comment: after 3rd step it gave me this error `Unable to locate package docker-ce`

Comment: I think u have installed ubuntu 32 bit version. Can u check it and let me know? To install docker you need to have following versions: Yakkety 16.10
Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
Trusty 14.04 (LTS)

Comment: I checked , it is x86_64 and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: mkae sure you have done the per-requisites steps properly as mentioned on this page. That error means you have not downloaded the respective package name docker-ce as your using the technique Install using the Repository. Here, its straight forward https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository